# FMX System messaging to send a pointer(?)

Tags: android, c++, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder 10.2.

In Android, I would like to send messages from various threads, including the main thread, to the main GUI thread. In Windows, I could post a message and assign an LPARAM or WPARAM to the address of some instance of a struct or class.

I'm trying to use `System.Messaging.TMessageManager` to do the same thing, similar to the example here: [System.Messaging (C++)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/System.Messaging_(C%2B%2B)). But I can only send 'simple' types, like `UnicodeString` or `int`. I haven't worked out how to send a pointer, assuming it's even possible at all.

I would like to send a struct/class instance like this:

```
class TSendResult
{
public:
    String Message;
    unsigned int Value;
    int Errno;

    __fastcall TSendResult(void);
    __fastcall ~TSendResult();
};
```

If this can be done, how do I write this? I managed to get one version to compile, but got a linker error:

> error: undefined reference to 'vtable for System::Messaging::TMessage__1<TSendResult>'

Form constructor:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    TMessageManager* MessageManager = TMessageManager::DefaultManager;
    TMetaClass* MessageClass = __classid(TMessage__1<TSendResult>);
    TMessageListenerMethod ShowReceivedMessagePointer = &(this->MMReceiveAndCallBack);
    MessageManager->SubscribeToMessage(MessageClass, ShowReceivedMessagePointer);
}
```

Button click handler:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::SpeedButton1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    ...

    TSendResult *SPtr = new TSendResult();
    SPtr->Message = "All good";
    SPtr->Value = 10;
    SPtr->Errno = 0;
    TMessageManager* MessageManager = TMessageManager::DefaultManager;
    TMessage__1<TSendResult>* Message = new TMessage__1<TSendResult>(*SPtr); // <-- this doesn't look right...
    MessageManager->SendMessage(Sender, Message, false);
}
```

Function that captures messages:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::MMReceiveAndCallBack(System::TObject* const Sender,
        System::Messaging::TMessageBase* const M)
{
    TMessage__1<TSendResult>* Message = dynamic_cast<TMessage__1<TSendResult>*>(M);
    if (Message) {
        ShowMessage(Message->Value.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TMessage__1<T>` is a C++ class implementation for the Delphi Generic [`TMessage<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Messaging.TMessage) class.  Unfortunately, there is a documented limitation when using Delphi Generic classes in C++, which is why you are getting a linker error:

[How to Handle Delphi Generics in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Generics_in_C%2B%2B)

> Delphi generics are exposed to C++ as templates. However, it is important to realize that the instantiations occur on the Delphi side, not in C++. Therefore, **you can only use these template for types that were explicitly instantiated in Delphi code**.
>
> ...
>
> If C++ code attempts to use a Delphi generic for types that were not instantiated in Delphi, you'll get errors at link time.

Which is why `TMessage__1<UnicodeString>` works but `TMessage__1<TSendResult>` does not, as there is an instantiation of `TMessage<UnicodeString>` present in the Delphi RTL.  Whoever wrote the [C++ example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/System.Messaging_(Delphi)) you are looking at was likely not aware of this limitation and was just translating the [Delphi example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/System.Messaging_(Delphi)) as-is.

That being said, you have two choices:

1. Add a Delphi `.pas` unit to your C++ project, implementing `TSendResult` as a Delphi `record`, and defining an instantiation of `TMessage<TSendResult>` for it.  Then you can use that unit in your C++ code (C++Builder will generate a C++ `.hpp` file for you when the `.pas` file is compiled), eg:

```pascal
unit MyMessageTypes;

interface

uses
  System.Messaging;

type
  TSendResult = record
    Message: String;
    Value: UInt32;
    Errno: Integer;
  end;

  TSendResultMsg = TMessage<TSendResult>;

implementation

initialization
  TSendResultMsg.Create.Free;
finalization

end.
```

```cpp
#include "MyMessageTypes.hpp"

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SubscribeToMessage(__classid(TSendResultMsg), &MMReceiveAndCallBack);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::SpeedButton1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    ...

    TSendResult Res;
    Res.Message = _D("All good");
    Res.Value = 10;
    Res.Errno = 0;

    TSendResultMsg *Message = new TSendResultMsg(Res);
    TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SendMessage(this, Message, true);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::MMReceiveAndCallBack(System::TObject* const Sender,
    System::Messaging::TMessageBase* const M)
{
    const TSendResultMsg* Message = static_cast<const TSendResultMsg*>(M);
    ShowMessage(Message->Value.Message);
}
```

2. rather than using `TMessage__1` at all, you can instead derive `TSendResult` directly from [`TMessageBase`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Messaging.TMessageBase), eg:

```cpp
class TSendResultMsg : public TMessageBase
{
public:
    String Message;
    unsigned int Value;
    int Errno;
};

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SubscribeToMessage(__classid(TSendResultMsg), &MMReceiveAndCallBack);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::SpeedButton1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    ...

    TSendResultMsg *Message = new TSendResultMsg;
    Message->Message = _D("All good");
    Message->Value = 10;
    Message->Errno = 0;
    TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SendMessage(this, Message, true);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::MMReceiveAndCallBack(System::TObject* const Sender,
    System::Messaging::TMessageBase* const M)
{
    const TSendResultMsg* Message = static_cast<const TSendResultMsg*>(M);
    ShowMessage(Message->Message);
}
```

Comment: Option 2 seemed the easiest so I tried that. Worked very well! One more thing, what does the bool ADispose parameter of SendMessage() do? Delete the TSendResultMsg instance after exiting MMReceiveAndCallBack()? Many thanks!

Comment: @PeterStefanos I believe so, yes.

Comment: Another thing I've found, unless I'm not understanding something, is that it looks like the function: 
void __fastcall SendMessage(System::TObject* const Sender, TMessageBase* AMessage, bool ADispose)
is ignoring the "ADispose" parameter. I'm calling this function with the parameter set to false but the instance gets destroyed anyway.
I have managed to work around it though...

Comment: @PeterStefanos I don't have the RTL source code for 10.2 handy to look at, but `ADispose` probably has an effect only on non-[ARC-based platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers), like Android. Note that Embarcadero has [moved away from ARC-based object management in 10.4](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/What%27s_New#Unified_Memory_Management).